# How to write an ElementTree with UTF-8 stripped out

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, tostring, elementtree

I have a giant (50MB) XML ElementTree that I've generated and somewhere in the raw data were some UTF-8 letters that didn't get stripped out. ElementTree.write and .tostring seem to choke on unicode even though there's an "encoding='UTF-8'" option in tostring. The docs are rather limited and I'm not even sure that tostring is UTF-8 friendly (looking at the source).

So my question - how do I strip this whole elementtree of any non-ascii characters so I can write this monster to disk (which took 8 hours to generate)? I have pickled it for now. I also used a function called latin1_to_ascii on most of the data:

```
def latin1_to_ascii(unicrap):
        """
        This takes a UNICODE string and replaces Latin-1 characters with
        something equivalent in 7-bit ASCII. Anything not converted is deleted.
    #the unicode hammer approach: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/251871-latin1-to-ascii-the-unicode-hammer/
    """
    xlate={0xc0:'A', 0xc1:'A', 0xc2:'A', 0xc3:'A', 0xc4:'A', 0xc5:'A',
            0xc6:'Ae', 0xc7:'C',
            0xc8:'E', 0xc9:'E', 0xca:'E', 0xcb:'E',
            0xcc:'I', 0xcd:'I', 0xce:'I', 0xcf:'I',
            0xd0:'Th', 0xd1:'N',
            0xd2:'O', 0xd3:'O', 0xd4:'O', 0xd5:'O', 0xd6:'O', 0xd8:'O',
            0xd9:'U', 0xda:'U', 0xdb:'U', 0xdc:'U',
            0xdd:'Y', 0xde:'th', 0xdf:'ss',
            0xe0:'a', 0xe1:'a', 0xe2:'a', 0xe3:'a', 0xe4:'a', 0xe5:'a',
            0xe6:'ae', 0xe7:'c',
            0xe8:'e', 0xe9:'e', 0xea:'e', 0xeb:'e',
            0xec:'i', 0xed:'i', 0xee:'i', 0xef:'i',
            0xf0:'th', 0xf1:'n',
            0xf2:'o', 0xf3:'o', 0xf4:'o', 0xf5:'o', 0xf6:'o', 0xf8:'o',
            0xf9:'u', 0xfa:'u', 0xfb:'u', 0xfc:'u',
            0xfd:'y', 0xfe:'th', 0xff:'y',
            0xa1:'!', 0xa2:'{cent}', 0xa3:'{pound}', 0xa4:'{currency}',
            0xa5:'{yen}', 0xa6:'|', 0xa7:'{section}', 0xa8:'{umlaut}',
            0xa9:'{C}', 0xaa:'{^a}', 0xab:'<<', 0xac:'{not}',
            0xad:'-', 0xae:'{R}', 0xaf:'_', 0xb0:'{degrees}',
            0xb1:'{+/-}', 0xb2:'{^2}', 0xb3:'{^3}', 0xb4:"'",
            0xb5:'{micro}', 0xb6:'{paragraph}', 0xb7:'*', 0xb8:'{cedilla}',
            0xb9:'{^1}', 0xba:'{^o}', 0xbb:'>>', 
            0xbc:'{1/4}', 0xbd:'{1/2}', 0xbe:'{3/4}', 0xbf:'?',
            0xd7:'*', 0xf7:'/',0x92:'a'
            }
    r = ''
    for i in unicrap:
            if xlate.has_key(ord(i)):
                    r += xlate[ord(i)]
            elif ord(i) >= 0x80:
                    pass
            else:
                    r += str(i)
    return r
```

that "nuclear option" function only works on strings, and now that I have the data in an Element I can't seem to strip the stuff I missed.

Comment: 8 hours? Are you using `xml.etree.ElementTree` or `xml.etree.cElementTree`? Could be a very productive key stroke ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to explain "somewhere in the raw data were some UTF-8 letters that didn't get stripped out" -- like what is a "UTF-8 letter", and why you want to strip them out.

It would also help if you explained what "ElementTree.write and .tostring seem to choke on unicode" means. Please edit your question to show the full error message and traceback.

Why do you want to used that function to bash your unicode into ASCII? Is it merely to overcome the problems that you are having?

It is probable that you are feeding `str` objects encoded in UTF-8 to ElementTree. Don't do that. Feed it `unicode` objects, and it just works:

```
>>> e = et.Element('root')
>>> e.text = u''.join(unichr(i) for i in xrange(0x400, 0x408))
>>> e.text
u'\u0400\u0401\u0402\u0403\u0404\u0405\u0406\u0407'
```

If you must have ASCII output (you're communicating over a 7-bit-wide channel?):

```
>>> et.tostring(e)
'<root>&#1024;&#1025;&#1026;&#1027;&#1028;&#1029;&#1030;&#1031;</root>'
```

UTF-8 works:

```
>>> et.tostring(e, 'UTF-8')
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n<root>\xd0\x80\xd0\x81\xd0\x82\xd0\x83\xd0\x84\xd0\x85\xd0\x86\xd0\x87</root>"
```

You should use the [ElementTree.write method](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) to write your file, in preference to using 'tostring'; it saves double-handling.

Comment: The output of this python script is an XML file interpreted by another proprietary program that only accepts ascii-Us or latin1, not unicode. So is there any convenience way to modify every element and subelement, tag, tail, etc in an ElementTree as if it was a string? That would allow me to just read each letter and return character with ord[128] or less. But haven't seen anything like that offered yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'd run the process again, decoding the input strings to unicode during the tree creation.  Eight hours may be a long time, but you can do other things instead of waiting for pointers on in-memory patching from others.

Make sure to test on a small subset of the data to confirm your code works before continuing on.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds to me like the problem is more likely to be the encoding of the output file-like that you're working with.  could you provide more code for how you're trying to write it out?  I don't see how `ElementTree.write()` and `ElementTree.tostring()` could be choking on it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay even if you guys think I'm crazy for doing it this way, it works:

I opened the pickle file in Notepad++ and manually found all the "\x??" characters with regex, and removed them. Then I imported the pickle into python to save as an XML file using ElementTree at the command line:

> > > f = open('pulsewire/pulse_cleaned.pickle','rb')
> > >
> > > import pickle
> > >
> > > data = pickle.load(f)
> > >
> > > import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
> > >
> > > bob = ET.ElementTree(data) <-- needed to wrap the Element in Tree first
> > >
> > > bob.write("pulsewire/testtree.xml")